# Getting attribute value by parent class name

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I have a slider, and on swipe I am trying to get the attribute value of the centered element. my js doesn't seem to work.

```js
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("owl-item active center").children("item").attr("data-price");
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<div class="owl-item active center" style="width: 340px; margin-right: 0px;">
  <div class="item" data-price="200" data-name="Car 2" data-color="Green">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `children()` , `on()`, etc.. are jQuery methods

Comment: I think `children` is available in javascript as well. It returns only the element child nodes, while `childNodes` returns both element and text nodes.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj : `children` is a property not a method in case of js also you can't apply it for nodeList

Comment: Can some one suggest me a way of getting that attribute value

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the below `children` is more of a property than a method:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("owl-item active center")[0].children
```

hence you cannot use it as a method.

Besides that there's not such thing as `attr` - you can use for ex:

```
domElement.getAttribute("class")
```

Answer (score 0):

`.children` is a read-only property that returns a live `HTMLCollection` of the child elements of Node.

so in order to select the element with specific class you need to verify every single child node and then return attribute of that child node.

**Sample Code:**

```
// pEl is a reference to a <p> element
var elementChildren = pEl.children;
for (var i = 0; i < elementChildren.length; i++) {
    console.log(elementChildren[i].tagName);
    // NOTE: elementChildren is a live list, adding or removing children from pEl
    // will change the members of elementChildren immediately
}
```

> `pEl.children` is a HTMLCollection, which is an ordered collection of DOM elements that are children of elementNodeReference. If there are no element children, then elList contains no elements and has a length of 0.

Reference : [ParentNode.Children from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)